# Is there a way to set the default response format for an entire Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, routes

I don't want to set the default format for every resource, but instead just set it for all of them in 1 go. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default format in your `ApplicationController`, and all the rest of your controllers should inherit.

```
#ApplicationController
before_filter :set_format

def set_format
  request.format = 'xml'
end
```

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. What about the routes?

Comment: I see it everywhere specified as something like: `match 'posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :defaults => { :format => 'xml' }`